# Как исправить скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу чтобы по движению мыши камера поворачивалась, вокруг игрока, для этого я написал вот такой скрипт:

```cs
float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
if (!JumpCheckWall & !pause)
{
  if (holdCamera)
  {
    PlayerCamera.transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.up, x * sens);
    PlayerCamera.transform.RotateAround(Player.transform.position, Vector3.right, y * sens);
  }
  else
  {
    Player.transform.Rotate(0, x * sens, 0);
  }
}
```

Но по итогу камера вертится не совсем вокруг игрока. Подскажите как исправить или дополнить?

Comment: Что значит "не совсем вокруг игрока"? Камера смещается? Камера крутится не вокруг центра игрока, а вокруг, например, его руки? Камера крутится в неправильных направлениях?

Comment: камера крутится не вокруг центра игрока, вернее не всегда вокруг центра.

Comment: Возможно центр объекта (pivot) смещается как-то... Попробуй движение камеры вокруг игрока поставить в LateUpdate, но скорее всего тебе придётся что-то умнажать на Time.deltaTime.